# How to set two colors in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to split navigation bar into two parts or need to add any custom view, to add two colors in navigation bar like below-

If I put below code-

It applied on whole navigation bar, Not only left corner.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "triangle"),for:.default)
```

[image]

Comment: You have to show the community you tried something. Its a simple image.

Comment: No, Its not a simple image. I put an image to overview, Actually on behalf of select a tableView cell, these both color will change.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, design your two-color image beforehand or draw it in code and call `setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624968-setbackgroundimage

Comment: But I want to change both colors on the selection of the different cell, I can't put an image

Comment: gradients ? @matt

Comment: When the selection changes change the image!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the background image of navigation bar like this:

```
if condition {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg1"), for: .default)
} else {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg2"), for: .default)
}
```

where bg1 is:
[image: bg1]

and bg 2 is:
[image: bg2]

and the result is:

[image: Result]

Keep in mind:

- You can color your image in code if you want more dynamic range of colors.
- You can use multiple `imageView`s behind navigation bar and set colors un them. (One for left part and one for right). And hide the navigation bar background image. So the illusion looks same.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw required gradient (OR two distinct non-gradient color) image with swift code first and then set it to the header.

**Creating an Image with an Image Renderer**

Use the `image(actions:)` method to create an image (`UIImage` object) with an image renderer. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761714/8238512

**To set created image above you already know**

Use the above generated `image` to set in `navigationBar`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(< *useAboveGeneratedImage* >),for:.default)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a custom navigation bar. Make a UIView and add some delegates for back buttons, hamburger menu (if required).