# Stroke a CGPath with a gradient along its length

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

Is it possible to create a gradient that strokes along a path?

My understanding is that `CAGradientLayer` or `CGGradient` will provide a gradient from, say, top to bottom. Since they don't support stroking along the path, I'm stumped.

I would even be OK with stretching an image (containing the gradient) along the path. Is that possible?

[image: Example of desired stroke effect]

In my case, I'd be stroking an arc (from CGPathAddArc). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, there is no built-in support for this, so what sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: After some more research, since I'm just doing this on an arc of a circle, I could probably make a shader for it, or use a mask with this project's output: https://github.com/tadija/AEConicalGradient.

Comment: Getting some reassurance this is not built-in is actually a useful answer, thanks @matt!.

Comment: "since I'm just doing this on an arc of a circle" Then that's what you should have asked! What you asked was illustrated with a specific shape to be stroked in a specific way. So that _wasn't_ in fact your question?

Comment: I did say I was stroking an arc, which might offer a simpler solution. The image illustrates the more general case.